# How to Import and Update variable products using WP All Import plugin?

Tags: updating, wpallimport

I want to upload variant products in batches, but the upload has never been successful. After uploading, each time it becomes multiple simple products. I don’t know where the problem is. Can I upload variant products in batches using one form file like the following? ? Or do I have to prepare two form files?

example:
Like below, a product has 2 colors and 5 sizes, how can I upload successful variant products? If someone taught me, I'd pay a small tip to say thank you. I just need you to demonstrate remotely and give me a sample of the product.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If You are using trial version it doesn't support variations. Guess it is the same for those illegal versions.

You can use pimwick bulk edit to change them to variable, but only 800 products at the time so if You have 20000 products it will take some time.

Smartmanager pro can update all at once.